# How to specify if condition such that I can apply a function to a subset of my dataframe (that is the if statement)?

Tags: r, if-statement, subset

I want to apply a function to a subset of my dataframe. Let this function be `CrossTable()` from {gmodels} which gives you a crosstab for two categorial variables. My question is not specifically about that function though, and ideally the same solution should apply to any other function, too, such as `table()`.

Now, I know how to subset dataframes, save the output and work with it, but what if I wanted to do all of this in one short step?

Here's my data and here's what I tried:

```
mydata <- data.frame(var1=c(rep(1:3,5)),
                     var2=c(5,1,1,4,2,3,5,2,2,5,1,2,4,1,1))

library(gmodels)
CrossTable(mydata$var1, mydata$var2, digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS") # For the whole dataset

if (mydata$var1>1) CrossTable(mydata$var1, mydata$var2, digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS")
```

The if condition yields the warning "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used", and I assume this is because for some reason `if (condition) statement` cannot be applied to vectors from dataframes. Is that correct? In STATA, where you can just type `if var ==x` this seems to work very differently.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% filter(var>1) %>% CrossTable(mydata$var1, mydata$var2, digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS")
```

This is already plan B, and I would really like to go with plan A, but neither does this tidyverse solution seem to do the trick, because `CrossTable()` like so many other functions (such as `table()`) cannot handle tidyselect objects.

```
CrossTable(mydata$var1[mydata$var1>1], mydata$var2, digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS")
```

This is plan C, and in that very order, this is my least favored option. So it's a good thing this doesn't work either, because obviously it produces two vectors of different length: `var1` will be shorter than `var2` by five observations

Does anyone have a solution or maybe even multiple solutions? Can anyone tell me how to make plan a through c work? That would be great!

Comment: @akrun With all due respect, but I don't think this duplicates what you linked to. My questions is not exclusively about subsetting but more about how you combine it with other functions in the same line of code and whether it is possible to use if-statements to achieve that.

Comment: Sure, that's true, but all-in-one was the condition. ;)

Comment: @akrun Not really though, if you look at the second and third option Ronak proposed.

Comment: Okay, i only checked the first option as I have eye sight issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal case, would be to subset the data and use the data in the function that you want to use

```
mydf <- subset(mydata, var1 > 1)
CrossTable(mydf$var1, mydf$var2, digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS")
```

The `if` condition doesn't subset the data it just checks for the condition.

If you don't want to subset the data and do that in one go, you could filter the values from both the terms

```
CrossTable(mydata$var1[mydata$var1 > 1], mydata$var2[mydata$var1 > 1], digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS")
```

Or using `dplyr`, we could do

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  filter(var1 > 1) %>%
  {CrossTable(.$var1, .$var2, digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS")}
```

Comment: OK thanks that works and I know it would be better to do this in two steps. Thank you also for fixing my plan b and c. But can you think of a way to make the if statement work as well? Or is this impossible? Why can't I let R check for a condition to be true and then on the basis of that apply the function?

Comment: @FabianHabersack `if` condition can only check for the condition and not subset the data, to subset you might need to use another function. If you want R to check for condition to be true and then apply the function you can use my 1st answer or even Joe's answer which subsets the data in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be,

```
with(mydata[mydata$var1 > 1,], CrossTable(var1, var2, digits=2, expected=F, prop.r=T, prop.c=F, prop.t=F, format="SPSS"))
```